# How to process remote XML files with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm processing remote XML (by just providing URL to XSLT processor) and I can't make it "fetch" additional XML resources. I read similar questions here, but none of them seem like applicable here.

Here is excerpt of remote XML that is being processed:

```
...
<item>
    <position>1</position>
    <rec id="05a59ca2"/>
</item>
<item>
    <position>2</position>
    <rec id="48e7c3f1"/>
</item>
...
```

Now these `id` attributes can be used to refer remote XML source (http://some-server/id) where additional details about each record is stored, and I would like to be able to process them with same XSLT without using other tools, for convenience and simplicity.

So, can I process remote XML files with XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most certainly do this using the document function

**example:**

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="concat('http://mysite.com/',$id)" />
<xsl:variable name="IDmeta" select="document($url)"/>
```

to test you can do

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$IDmeta"/>
```

to see what the format is

**reference**

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp

Comment: Isn't `document()` only available for local files? Just in case I tried it as in your example and got `Error retrieving resource` for provided URL.

Comment: You know what? It works beautifully! Not for first example, but for another with absolute path to XML file. For some reason, I didn't considered `document()` as from what I have read over Internet I was under impression that it's not that easy ;) edit: you were faster

Comment: superb, just been doing some things with it myself to dynamically load a pre defined list of things also note you can use xpath on this aswell example like document('your-path.xml')/Categories/Category[@ID = $CategoryID]

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for that :)