# Fetch remote XML with saxon

Tags: java, xml, command-line-interface, sax, saxon

How can I [fetch](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) remote `XML` from saxon?

```
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ java -cp /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar net.sf.saxon.Query fetch.note.text.xq 
Static error on line 2 at column 2 of file:/home/thufir/saxon/fetch.note.text.xq near {...ww.w3schools.com/xml/note.x...} 
  XPST0081: Namespace prefix 'fetch' has not been declared
Static error(s) in query
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ cat fetch.note.text.xq 

fetch:xml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", map { 'chop': true() })


thufir@dur:~/saxon$
```

which works from `BaseX`.

Simple hello world [runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53991245/262852) okay:

```
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ java -cp /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar net.sf.saxon.Query test.xq 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results><message>Hello World!</message></results>thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$
```

Might `expath` provide this [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3012932/262852), perhaps?  Or I should be using `xslt` for [fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11633134/262852).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard XPath functions like `doc('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml')`. Processor specific modules like BaseX's `fetch` are usually not portable.

Comment: Exactly:  standard XPath.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why you have edited your question to now ask about the `doc` function I suggested, the XQuery code I suggested is as shown in my answer: `doc('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml')`. So your XQuery file (e.g. `foo.xq`) would contain that code and you would then call Saxon as you already do. e.g. `java -cp /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar net.sf.saxon.Query foo.xq`.

Comment: I was running it with `java -jar ..` which barfed.  Thought I had the query wrong, but it was the way I was invoking `Saxon`.  Usage problem.  I was trying to narrow the question by editing it.  I'll change it back for reference -- maybe it will help someone else :)